# Почему бот не может отредактировать пост в телеграмм канале?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Бот должен сделать пост в телеграмм канале, среагировать на оповещение из сообщества и отредактировать текст поста.

Пост делается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В сообщество приходить оповещение о посте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда дело доходит до редактирования, выдаёт ошибку, что сообщение нельзя отредактировать
aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageCantBeEdited: Message can't be edited

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Права у бота имеются, но почему-то пост не редактируется. Помогите пожалуйста. Вот код

```
from aiogram import types, executor, Bot, Dispatcher
from config import TOKEN, chanelID

bot = Bot(TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['send'])
async def send(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chanelID, 'текст')

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def content(message: types.Message):
    await bot.edit_message_text('новый текст', message.chat.id, message.message_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```